# HTTP to HTTPS redirect, nginx configuration is causing infinite request to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, linode

Hi I am new to Nginx and looking some help to redirect my http request to https.

I have two configuration on load balance with port 80 and 444 at Linode cloud system.

If request comes from https then load balancer if sending request to my serving tomcat after terminating SSL to LB.

If request comes from http then load balancer is sending to my nginx server which is redirecting request to https.

I see whenever, I start my nginx server, I see continues logs in my tomcat server of redirect url even no one is hitting my http url. I have following complete nginx.conf file.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
            listen       80 ;
            server_name  example.com;
            #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            rewrite  ^ https://$server_name/$request_uri permanent;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

            # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

            location =/ {
                 }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
            }
        }
```

Same configuration works perfectly, if I put IP address in place of actual domain name.

Following are the curl results based on location and I see in after redirecting from HTTPS location header is showing https://example.com/login which is doing correctly

```
# curl -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 07:43:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: close
Location: https://example.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.3</center>
</body>
</html>

# curl -i https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C3B65BD4E015F05705B585F5F8D70074; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://example.com/login
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 07:44:03 GMT
Connection: close

#curl -i https://example.com/login
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6B30D6D70672A99F13B2F441B2F2150E; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 07:44:18 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML context of login page>
```

Please suggest me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

To simply redirect all requests to port 80 to https, use the following configuration. No further lines are required, and might skip the purpose of the server:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    rewrite  ^  https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

This way, whichever host or even IP address will be forwarded to the https counterpart. If you are sure there'll be only one destination host, you may use it instead of the `$host` variable (do not enter a `/` afterwards):

```
    rewrite ^  https://example.com$request_uri permanent;
```

It'd be even better if you use `return`:

```
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    # or
    # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Since this is the only purpose of this `server` block, remove all other directives, like `root`, `location`, `error_page` and `include`.

Beware of additional files at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf`, they may overwrite these settings.

Reload nginx configuration and test. I suggest using cURL — here's the expected result:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2016 17:33:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Look and copy the `Location:` header content, then test again using cURL (use `-k` if you use a self-signed certificate):

```
curl -i https://example.com
```

The result should be from your tomcat application, and **NOT** another redirect to the same page. If the result is the same (safe from the date), then your LB is probably sending the https requests back to nginx, causing a loop.

Please note that the tomcat application may also be forwarding to https if it doesn't understand it's behind a proxy (the LB). In this case, you'll need to setup the application config to properly understand this (let me know if this is the case).

Comment: If I comment that line then how will rewrite URL to https?

Comment: and etc/nginx/conf.d/ is emty.

Comment: The load balancer holds the SSL certificate, then passes to tomcat, where you see  the redirects, right? So the redirect is being done at tomcat, not nginx. Probably the connection between the LB and tomcat is not encrypted and tomcat wants to serve a HTTPS page... Could you paste tomcat configuration?

Comment: I don't want to tight my tomcat with HTTPS and if I put https first time itself in browser then its working fine. HTTPS is terminating at LB and then LB is sending request to tomcat via HTTP.  I want to redirect my http to https so I used nginx. I have open two port mapping on LB level if HTTP:80 comes then I am sending to nginx which should redirect to 443 and if https comes to LB then its terminating to LB and sending to tomcat.

Comment: As per current configuration redirect happened at Nginx. Tomcat configuration is default configuration serving on http:8080.

Comment: @VijayKumarRajput, I've updated my answer with a more simple setup to avoid errors (and I was making one mistake by allowing the `/` between `$server_name` and `$request_uri`), and I also included some simple tests to verify if there's any other problem with nginx/tomcat configuration.

Comment: I have updated curl out put as you suggested and that seems correct to me but still I see tons of hits on my tomcat server and my configuration is still same.

Comment: Any time I restart nginx server, I see continuous logs on my tomcat server even no one hits from browser.

Answer (score 0):

I see that my Nginx server is exposed on public IP using port:80 and it was receiving traffic from unwanted hosts.

Since I had a default configuration in Nginx server block which was redirecting my all incoming http:80 traffic from any host to my tomcat on https:443, thats why I saw tons of logs in my tomcat server.

I had to add below configuration to my /etc/nginx.conf to redirect port:80 traffic to https if request is coming from my domain only.

```
if ($host ~ ^(example.com|www.example.com)$) {
         return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```